# How to create grid tables in word document report using R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

I was able to generate a word document report having a simple table using R markdown but I was not able to generate the report with table having grids.

I tried to create a reproducible code.

````
---
title: "Unable to create table having grids"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown simple table

Tables             Are           Cool
-------------     -----------   -----------
col 3 is         right-aligned  $1600 
col 2 is         centered         $12 
zebra stripes    are neat         $1"


## Table Does Not have grids in it.

+--------------+---------------+---------+
|Tables        | Are           | Cool    |
+==============+===============+=========+
|col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600   |
+--------------+---------------+---------+
|col 2 is      | centered      |   $12   |
+--------------+---------------+---------+
````

Comment: You can set custom css for your rmarkdown document that can control table appearance.

Comment: The markdown grid is just a markup, the HTML/PDF/Word table will not necessary have a grid -- it depends on the stylesheet/reference document used there.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But when I try to add custom style sheet, it doesn't support in word document, it only works for html document.

Comment: see the manual and the `--reference-docx` option

Comment: I tried to use reference-docx, but in that we cannot change the style of the table to grid.

Comment: I'm not sure... maybe some on the pandoc-discuss mailing list knows...